# Pre-emptive exception when trying to assign to something in a Python closure?

Tags: python-2.7, closures

```
def closure():
    a = 2
    def f():
        if a < 5:
            print a
    return f

closure()()
```

prints 2, which makes sense to me, because you can read closed-over variables.

```
def closure():
    a = 2
    def f():
        if a < 5:
            a += 1
            print a
    return f

closure()()
```

results in `File "closure_problems.py", line 4, in f
    if a < 5:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment`.

That makes sense to me too, because I know you can't assign to closed-over variables. But it's weird that the line number is referring to `if a < 5` instead of what seems like it should be the actual offending statement, `a += 1`.

And this

```
def closure():
    a = 2
    def f():
        if a < 5:
            print a
            a += 1
    return f

closure()()
```

results *only* in `File "closure_problems.py", line 4, in f
    if a < 5:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment`. It doesn't even print `2`, which I don't understand at all.

Is the interpreter trying to parse everything in the block (without evaluating it) in order to find out whether I'm talking about a local `a` or a global one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assigning `a` in a function makes `a` into a local variable for the `f()` function. But you can't use it before you have assigned it, which is why you get an error at the `if a < 5` statement.

> Is the interpreter trying to parse everything in the block (without evaluating it) in order to find out whether I'm talking about a local a or a global one?

Yes.

Or well, there is no trying, there is only doing.

Comment: But `if a < 5` is completely fine in the first example. Because in that context, `a` is interpreted as the `a` that's been closed over, instead of some new local variable that I didn't assign. It seems like Python is looking ahead to see what I'm going to do with `a` inside the `if` statement in order to decide which one I'm talking about at the beginning of the statement.

Comment: @EliRose Yes. In the first example, `a` is not a local variable.

Comment: Python isn't "looking head" so much as it has parsed the function to create the function object before executing it. A local var is *created* by assigning to it. If you peek inside the implementation details of the function object you can see it. Look at `closure().func_code.co_varnames`, `closure().func_code.co_freevars`, and `closure().func_closure` in each of your examples.

Comment: Ah, okay. I guess I was assuming that function parsing progressed in a linear fashion, like other Python code, but there's no reason that's necessarily true.

Comment: @EliRose There is no "other python code". Python parses the file and compiles it into byte code first. It executes it later. It does not parse one line and then execute it and then parse the next and execute that. I don't think any modern language does that, it would be very slow. :-)